# Cannot open an excel datasheet in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have following code, which opens excel and reads some data and outputs the data. I get error already on line 5. It looks like path is wrong. I have excel installed. $excel is not empty. Excel file is located in the correct location. I run ps1 script with  ."test excel.ps1". Powershell is opened in administrator mode.
Error is also below

```
# Create a new Excel COM object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
  
# Open the specified Excel file
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("F:\Tabele.xlsx")

# Select the sheet containing the data
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("LO1")

# Read the data from the specified range
$data = $worksheet.Range("B9:E24").Value

# Output the data to the console
$data

# Close the workbook and quit Excel
$workbook.Close($false)
$excel.Quit()
```

Error:
`PS F:> ."test excel.ps1"
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\test excel.ps1:5 char:1

- $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("F:\Tabele.xlsx")
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\test excel.ps1:8 char:1

- $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("LO1")
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\test excel.ps1:11 char:1

- $data = $worksheet.Range("B9:E24").Value
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At F:\test excel.ps1:17 char:1

- $workbook.Close($false)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

Exception calling "Quit" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
'{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))."
At F:\test excel.ps1:18 char:1

- $excel.Quit()
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastException`
  ```

Please help

I tried path with \ and /  and is the same. I tried to check if $excel exists and it exists, because I get same problem.

```
if ($excel) {  
# Open the specified Excel file
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("F:/Tabele.xlsx")
}
else {
    Write-Output "value excel is empty"
}
```

I have powershell version 5.1.19041.2364 and Excel from Office Professional 2019.

Comment: If powershell is running as admin then you need any instance of excel to run as admin. However it would be preferred to just run powershell unelevated or don’t have excel open when the script runs.

Comment: The amazing module [importexcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) by Doug fink is even easier, check it out. It doesn’t require excel to even be installed

Comment: I have just tried all combinations of open excel, closed excel, admin powershell and normal powershell. Nothing is working. Same error.

Comment: Add some logging to verify your assumptions - e.g. after ```$excel = ...``` put ```write-host "excel is null? $($null -eq $excel)"``` and maybe even ```write-host "workbooks is null? ($null -eq $excel.Workbooks)"``` - that'll help you narrow down excatly where the issue is...

Comment: Is there a simple example how to read cells B9:E24 from excel file with importexcel module? Cannot find it.

Comment: I tried to verify my assumption with your suggestion and I get: "excel is null? False
workbooks is null? ( -eq Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.Workbooks) " After above I get same error as in my original post. I have tried the script on another computer and it is working better (another problem for another question) and not showing these errors I have written about in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below function to import data from Excel:

```
Function Import-FromExcel
{
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [String]$WorkbookPath
         )

    # Constant values
    [int]$xlToRight = -4161; [int]$xlToLeft = -4159; [int]$xlUp = -4162; [int]$xlDown = -4121;

    If (($objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application)) { Write-Verbose "Created Excel application object" }
    Else { Write-Host "Unable to create Excel object on this computer. Check if you have Excel installed." -ForegroundColor Red; Return $Error[0].CategoryInfo.Category; }

    If(Test-Path -Path $WorkbookPath)
    {
        If(($objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($WorkbookPath))) { Write-Verbose "Opened $WorkbookPath successfully" } 
        Else { Write-Host "Unable to open $WorkbookPath." -ForegroundColor Red; Return $Error[0].Exception.Message }
    }
    Else { Return "Workbook not found $WorkbookPath!" }

    $objSheet = $objWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1)
    $TotalColumnsAddress = ($objSheet.Cells(1,$objSheet.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Address($false, $false)).ToString().Split(":")[0]
    $ColumnCount = $objSheet.Range("$($TotalColumnsAddress)1").End($xlToLeft).Column
    $RowCount = $objSheet.Range("A$($objSheet.Rows.Count)").End($xlUp).Row
    $LastColumnAddress = ($objSheet.Range("$($TotalColumnsAddress)1").End($xlToLeft).EntireColumn.Address($false,$false)).ToString().Split(":")[0]
    Write-Verbose "Total column address limit is $TotalColumnsAddress`n Whereas Last column in data is $LastColumnAddress"

    If ($ColumnCount -ge 1 -and $RowCount -ge 2) { Write-Verbose "Found $ColumnCount column and $RowCount rows of data in workbook."}
    Else 
    {
        Write-Host "No records found for processing. There should be at least one record/row apart from the header row in Workbook" -ForegroundColor Red
        Return "No records found in input workbook file"
    }

    Write-Verbose "Converting Excel data into an object."
    $ColHeaders = @()
    $ColHeaders = $objSheet.Range("A1:$($objSheet.Range("$($TotalColumnsAddress)1").End($xlToLeft).Address($false,$false))").value2
    
    # Replace blank column headers with Column'n'
    Write-Verbose "Generating object headers from workbook"
    For($i=1; $i -le $ColHeaders.Count; $i++) 
    {
        if($ColHeaders[1,$i] -eq "" -or $ColHeaders[1,$i] -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Column $i was found empty hence assigning column name as Column$i"
            $ColHeaders[1,$i] = "Column$i"
        }
    }

    $objOutData = @()

    $DataRange = $objSheet.Range("A2:$($LastColumnAddress)$RowCount").Rows

    Write-Verbose "Started processing rows/records from workbook"
    For($curRow=2; $curRow -le $RowCount; $curRow++)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Working on row number $curRow."
        $rowData = $DataRange.Rows | Where-Object { $_.Row -eq $curRow } | %{$_.Value2}
        # Blank object for properties
        $objRecord = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        For($curColumn = 1; $curColumn -le $ColumnCount; $curColumn++)
        {
            # Adjusting the number format for column
            If($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat -eq "General")
            {
                $ValueData = $rowData[$curColumn-1]
            }
            Else
            {
                If(($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat).ToString() -cmatch "d" -or
                   ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat).ToString() -cmatch "M" -or
                   ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat).ToString() -cmatch "yy")
                   {
                        If(($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "h:" -and
                           ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "mm")
                        {
                            $ValueData = [System.DateTime]::FromOADate($rowData[$curColumn-1]).ToString('ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            $ValueData = [System.DateTime]::FromOADate($rowData[$curColumn-1]).ToString('dd-MMM-yyyy')
                        }
                   }
                   ElseIf(($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "h:" -or
                           ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "mm" -or
                           ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "ss")
                   {
                        $ValueData = [System.DateTime]::FromOADate($rowData[$curColumn-1]).ToString('hh:mm:ss')
                   }
                   ElseIf(($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "0" -or
                           ($objSheet.Cells($curRow, $curColumn).NumberFormat) -cmatch "0.0")
                   {
                        $value = 0
                        If([double]::TryParse($rowData[$curColumn-1], [ref]$value)) { $ValueData = $value }
                        Else { $ValueData = $rowData[$curColumn-1] }
                   }
                   Else 
                   { $ValueData = $rowData[$curColumn-1] }
            }
            $objRecord | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $ColHeaders[1,$curColumn] -Value $ValueData -Force
        }
        $objOutData += $objRecord
    }

    # Quit Excel and release all resources.
    $objWorkbook.Close($false)
    $objExcel.Quit()
    Write-Verbose "Successfully processed and closed Excel application"

    # Supress errors temporarily
    $oldErrorActionPreference =  $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($RowCount) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ColumnCount) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($DataRange) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objSheet) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWorkbook) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Try { do { $comReleaser = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objRecord) } while($comReleaser -gt -1) } Catch {}
    Write-Verbose "Released all the Com objects."
    $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorActionPreference

    Return $objOutData
}
```